# Vim color scheme PHP $_POST variable categorized as statement

Tags: php, vim, syntax, syntax-highlighting, color-scheme

I am editing a Vim color scheme for PHP. Why are variables such as `$_POST` and `$_SESSION` categorized as statements? They use the same color as if statements, for example. Other variables will have a different coloring. Also, the dollar sign is categorized as statement.

How do I change the coloring of these separately?

[image]

Comment: @garfbradaz I posted an image, because the question is about the syntax highlighting.

Comment: My sincere apologies you did - my bad and ignore me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find out which syntax group causes the highlighting. `:syn list` shows all active groups, but it's easier when you install the [SyntaxAttr.vim - Show syntax highlighting attributes of character under cursor](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=383) plugin.

For me, this results to the following mappings (Vim 8.0.55):

```
"if":   phpConditional -> Conditional links to Statement
"$":    phpVarSelector -> Operator links to Statement
"POST": phpIntVar -> Identifier
```

In general, colorschemes define a basic set of styles, for example `Constant`, `Identifier`, `Statement`. Then, (still generic) variants are defined: `String` is-a kind of `Constant`. Syntax plugins then link to one of those. Your can see that for PHP in `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/php.vim`, in the `:hi def link` commands in the bottom of the script.

That gives the user several ways to configure the highlighting: If you don't see `String` as a kind of `Constant`, you can redefine that link, or override with a new custom style, and it will apply to all sorts of syntaxes. If you just want to tweak a certain language element (like `phpIntVar`), you can change that link, and it will be only for PHP and that element. And all of that can be done in your `~/.vimrc`!

Comment: Thank you for the extensive information. The var selector seems to work, but the int var does not change the color of `$_POST`. Any ideas?

Comment: I found it. It is called: phpSuperGlobal.